Problems in setting up configuration file directories for PoseNDF model
I am currently training the model on the MOYO dataset (A dataset containing complex yoga poses, multi-view videos, SMPL-X meshes, pressure and body center of mass) and I am unsure on how to structure my files as the training dataset says it has a size of zero and my code doesn't go beyond that. If anyone could help me out that would be great! I have followed the README.md of the PoseNDF model but I am stuck on how to use trainer.py to actually train the model. (I put in the command and my debugging statements say that the dataset has a size of zero. I believe there is something wrong with my yaml file and my structure with the dataset. I have managed to get the train.npz files for the SMPLX format. I can't quite figure out what structure the model is looking for).
This is the command I tried and the output I get:
python trainer.py --config=configs/moyo.yaml
Initial data files: 4
Initial moyo files: 350
Filtered data files: 2
Filtered moyo files: 312
Final dataset size: 2
Training dataset size: 2
Creating DataLoader with dataset size: 2
No checkpoints found at ../MOYO-SMPLX/main_lrelu_l1_1e-05__5000_dist1.0_eik1.0_man1.0/checkpoints/
Starting training...
Training dataset size: 0
Starting epoch 0
No valid training steps in epoch 0, skipping checkpoint save.
Epoch 0 finished with loss: 0.0, average loss: 0.0
Starting epoch 1
No valid training steps in epoch 1, skipping checkpoint save.
Epoch 1 finished with loss: 0.0, average loss: 0.0
Starting epoch 2

It just carries on like this.
Here is the tree structure for my MOYO dataset:
tree ../MOYO-SMPLX
../MOYO-SMPLX
├── Female
│   ├── train
│   │   ├── female_train
│   │   │   ├── [raw data]
│   │   └── female_train.npz
│   └── val
│       ├── [raw data]
├── Neutral
│   ├── train
│   │   ├── neutral_train
│   │   │   ├── [raw data]
│   │   └── neutral_train.npz
│   └── val
│       ├── [raw data]
├── Sample
│   ├── Female
│   │   └── train
│   │       └── female_train.npz
│   └── Neutral
│       └── train
│           └── neutral_train.npz
├── Training
│   ├── Female
│   │   └── train
│   │       └── female_train.npz
│   ├── Neutral
│   │   └── train
│   │       └── neutral_train.npz
│   └── train
│       ├── female_train.npz
│       └── neutral_train.npz
└── main_lrelu_l1_1e-05__5000_dist1.0_eik1.0_man1.0
    ├── checkpoints
    ├── config.yaml
    └── summary
        ├── [events output]

Here is the moyo.yaml file:
data:
  data_dir: ../MOYO-SMPLX/Training/ # Training data directory
  moyo_dir: ../MOYO-SMPLX/
  sample_pt: 100000
  dc: dc
  num_pts: 5000
  single: False
  flip: False
  sample_distribution: [0.5, 0.5]
  sample_sigmas: [ 0.0, 0.001]
experiment:
  bodymodel: smpl
  root_dir: ../MOYO-SMPLX # Where to save checkpoints and final trained model_quat #todo
  data_name: PoseData
  type: BaseTrainer
  inp_name: xyz
  exp_name: main
  num_part: 21
  val: False
  test: False

model:
  DFNet:
    name: 'DFNet'
    total_dim: 960
    in_dim: 126
    num_parts: 21
    num_layers: 5
    ff_enc: False
    dims: "256,512,1024,512,256,64"
    act: lrelu
    beta: 100
  StrEnc:
    use: True
    name: 'StructureEncoder'
    out_dim: 6
    in_dim: 84
    num_part: 21
    pose_enc: False #todo
    num_layers: 2
    ff_enc: False
    act: lrelu
    beta: 100
train:
  pde: False
  device: cuda
  batch_size: 4
  continue_train: true
  optimizer: Adam
  optimizer_param: 0.00001 #1e-4  #1e-4 for lr and 0.9 for momentum
  eval: False
  num_worker: 12
  max_epoch: 200000
  loss_type: l1   #todo
  clamp_dist: 0.0  # 2dsphere data is prepared in such way
  man_loss: 1.0
  dist: 1.0
  eikonal: 1.0
  body_enc: true
  disp_reg: true
  grad: false
  train_stage_1: 100000  #pretrain weight prediction
  train_stage_2: 100000  #freeze weight prediction
  square: False
  abs: True

